# Selecting a value from a list of values in a report on access 2007

Tags: list, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table that has a field named "number" which is populated by a list of values, between 0 to 6.

I then have a query where I search the number of records on each "number".

On the query it works, and I get the number of records for each "number", for example:
- 10 cases for 0
- 5 cases for 1
- ....

But then when I create a report based on that query, it displays the list of values from the "number" field, with the value in question highlighted...

I want to show only the highlighted number on each row, and not the whole list of values...

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us sample data and the query you're using for the report's record source.  What do you mean by "value in question highlighted"?  Are you still talking about a value in an Access report?

Comment: If possible take a snapshot of your form and your query (or even better if you can provide us the SQL for your query).

Comment: Hi, I can't add a printscreen because I still need to increase my "reputation" on the site, hope to get there soon :)

Comment: Hi @HansUp, the "number" field is of type "text" and populated by a list of values (0,1,2,3,4,5,6). When I run the query, I get that 0 appears X times, 1 appears Y times, 2 appears Z times, and so on... But when i run the report based on that query, I get the (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) with the number in question in bold... I want it to show only the bolded number and not the other options on that particular row!
Hi alexandre-p-levasseur here's the code:
    SELECT Count(Pacient.[ID-SI]) AS [ContarDeID-SI], Pacient.[Number]
FROM Pacient 
GROUP BY Pacient.[Number];

Comment: Hi Everyone, just a small note to my really (now I see...) dumb question... I just needed to change the type of element to "text box" and now it only appears the value I wanted from the "value list"... sorry for all this mess :) and thanks for your help!